# Excel sheet copy past to HTML format

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have data in the source active sheet. Need to create another sheet with same name & past entire data from source to destination (the new sheet). But each shell data to HTML formate.

**Example:**
Source A1 value is "1234"

Destination A1 value should be `<html><body>1234</body></html>`

Below script can use to copy entire sheet to another sheet. But I need data with HTML formate.

```
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
```

Is there any chance special pate to HTML format?
could you help anybody?
Finally, each cell value should come as HTML format.

[image]

find out the script, but small changes required. Cell format is changing to normal. As shown in below screenshot. Any suggestion!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4gw1.png)

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is.  What specifically do you mean by HTML format?

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow!**  Please take a few minutes to check out the [tour] and there are also important tips in [ask] as well as tips about **providing examples** at [mcve].  We like to see that some effort has been made in finding a solution before asking for help (on a _specific_ problem), so please includes details about what you've tried so far.  More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Also see [ask] and the [tour].

Comment: There is nothing like this built-in to Excel.  You would need to use VBA or a formula to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=CONCATENATE("<html><body>",A1,"</body></html>")
```

You can put this formula in column B and drag this formula down to fill the rest of the cells.

Comment: Thank you Hellboy,

Comment: You are welcome! You can set answer as accepted so it won't reflect in list of Unanswered questions